# dygraph 1.1.1 appears to incorrectly detect range value for data source

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I've been struggling with trying to figure out how to get dygraphs to play nicely with my data. When it renders the chart, it cuts off a good chunk of the lines in the display. However if I scroll (shift + drag) to the left a little it rescales the view and includes all of the data. It looks like the drop off at the end of the graph is skewing the view of the chart.

It's really simple, I have a sample data file here: http://pasamio.com/~pasamio/dygraph/sample_data.json

And here's what I'm using to pull it in:

```
var dataURL = "http://pasamio.com/~pasamio/dygraph/sample_data.json";
var jsonData = null;

var jsonDataResult = $.ajax({
    url: dataURL,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: (
        function(data) {
            jsonData = data;
        })
});

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

var g = new Dygraph.GVizChart(document.getElementById("dg_div"));
g.draw(data, {"panEdgeFraction" : 0.1});
```

I've got a sample jsfiddle here that shows the bad case: https://jsfiddle.net/g6b6jp9z/5/

Any idea's what's going on here?

Comment: Your fiddle is broken. All I see is "Table has no columns."

Comment: Odd, it's working for me in Safari 10, what browser are you using?

Comment: Ok, fixed Fiddle link and verified the graphs render in Chrome. Chrome also displays the odd behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the repro. It looks like dygraphs is interpreting your values as strings, not numbers. Since GViz handles this correctly, this is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I fixed up the JSON to not emit the numbers as strings (just the dates) and that resolves the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [danvk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388951/danvk) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412788/dygraph-1-1-1-appears-to-incorrectly-detect-range-value-for-data-source?noredirect=1#comment70109744_41412788), the solution was to change the numbers from being wrapped in quotes causing them to be treated as strings to be just bare numbers in the JSON output. Thanks again to danvk :)

The original file had these sections:

```
"c": [
    {
        "v": "Date(2016, 10,  27, 00, 00, 00)"
    },
    {
        "v": "548"
    },
    {
        "v": "165"
    },
    {
        "v": "57"
    },
    {
        "v": "39"
    },
    {
        "v": "29"
    },
    {
        "v": "6"
    },
    {
        "v": "1"
    }
]
```

And the working version looks like this:

```
"c": [
    {
        "v": "Date(2016, 10,  27, 00, 00, 00)"
    },
    {
        "v": 548
    },
    {
        "v": 165
    },
    {
        "v": 57
    },
    {
        "v": 39
    },
    {
        "v": 29
    },
    {
        "v": 6
    },
    {
        "v": 1
    }
]
```